# Problema com CSS não aplicando no DIV

Tags: javascript, css3

Pessoal queria saber porque o atributo id da div nao esta sendo reconhecido pelo CSS, sendo que o nome do id da DIV está certinho no CSS.

```
  function nome () {
    var tela = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('id', 'screen')
    document.body.appendChild(tela)
  }

  nome()
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código deveria ser:

```
  function nome () {
    var tela = document.createElement('div')
    tela.setAttribute('id', 'screen')
    document.body.appendChild(tela)
  }

  nome()
```

Isso pois o valor da variavel tela não possui um tipo correto (esperado [HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement)) para que ele possa ser injetado no DOM. Em outras palavras, o método [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) retorna "void".
Na verdade, o CSS não está aplicando no seu elemento DIV pelo fato dele não existir, por causa da instrução errada. 
Quando você faz:

```
var tela = document.createElement("div").setAttribute("id","screen");
```

Você de fato cria a DIV, mas ainda ela não está no DOM.
E aqui você tenta injetá-la no DOM, mas pelo fato da variável `tela` ter um valor "nada" (undefined), essa DIV nunca é colocada no seu documento HTML:

```
document.body.appendChild(tela); // essa linha não faz sentido
```

Comment: como assim ? essa eu nao sabia.

Comment: devo ter escrito algo fora do padra nesta var?

Comment: vou ver isso,obrigado pela ajuda felipsmartins

Comment: @DanielSantos, veja a edição que explica o porquê.

Comment: ja consegui resolver,era um erro bem simples,apenas o js que deveria ser instanciado em baixo da tag body.

Comment: foi uma errada cabreira

Comment: por isso dizia que a variavel nao tinha um nodename

Comment: ele tinha que carregar o corpo da pagina primeiro,e nao o script externo porque assim o copilador nem saberia onde colocar a div,e sendo assim de fato a variavel nao ia ter valor nenhum,ao adicionada dentro de um  corpo que nao existe ainda na pagina.

Comment: demorei mas achei

Comment: obrigado amigo pelo recado sobre o possivel erro,me ajudou bastante eu dei uma pesquisada sobre esse nodename e descobri o porque